# OnClick redirect to a component with props using route

Tags: reactjs, routes, onclick, react-router-dom

I have a list of things, 
When I click on a line, I retrieved the element ID from my list with my **onClickDetail** function

After that I would like to redirect the user to a new component passing this element ID
How can I handle that ?

App.js route:

```
 <HashRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" component={Register} />
        <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" component={Page404} />
        <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" component={Page500} />
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <Route path="/" name="Home" component={DefaultLayout} />
        </PersistGate>
      </Switch>
      </Provider>
  </HashRouter>
```

Where I can click on my element (this.props.currentElement is an id) :

```
        <td><i className="fa fa-edit fa-lg " style={{color: '#63c2de'}}
 onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, this.props.currentElement)}></i></td>
```

My onclick function :

```
    handleClick = (currentElement) => {
           console.log('list ref' , currentElemnt); // display my id ok
return (
        <Link to={"/listDetail/" + currentElement}>my list detail id : {currentElement}</Link>)
    }
```

I though adding  in app.js

```
<Route path="/listDetail/:id" component={ListDetail}>
```

And add to my **onClickDetail** function

```
<Link to={"/listDetail/" + id}>my list detail id : {id}</Link>
```

But it's not working. Nothing Happen excepte the console.log

Maybe it's not the best way to do it, so I just wanted to know how to Handle OnClick to redirect my user to a new component passing props.

The story line should be :

- Homepage display List of thing
- Click on an element in the list
- element ID is retrieved, user is redirect to a component which display this specific element

Thanks a lot

Comment: Where is your `onClickDetail` function in the code? Could you include that as well, so all relevant code is in your question?

Comment: typo? `/listDeail/`  `"/listDetail/:id"`

Comment: I updated the original post, @TomFinney sorry my bad I change the name because it's revelant to my client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `HomePage` component, as it is rendered from a `<Route />`, it should receive the Router props such as `match` and `history`.

So, inside of your `onClick` function, you will simply need to do something like

```
function onClick(id) {
    this.props.history.push("/listDetail/" + id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I took a little bit of time to understand that I had to pass history though my compenent but thanks to you it works !

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `<Link/>`, you can use push method from `history` node package.

Install history: `npm install history`

Create a file history.js: 

    `import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
    const history = createHistory();
    export default history;`

import history where you want to change your url.

Your onClick function: `(url) => history.push(url)`;

import history where your router is:

`<Router history={history} />`

Try it this way :)